# Test that string begins with a specific substring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am using `validates_format with` to check that a string begins with the following characters:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64
```

Here is a typical string I want to test:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

My code is:

```
validates_format_of :imagebase64,  :with => %r{ \A(data:image/jpeg;base64) }i, :message => "is a invalid data uri base64 file"
```

and it's not working. How can I add something to the regexp so that it rejects if the string has any white space?

Comment: Try `:with => /\Adata:image\/jpeg;base64\S*\z/i` where `\S*` matches zero or more non-whitespace chars and `\z` matches the end of string. See http://rubular.com/r/HLu8n8M6QB

Comment: working thanks ! if you want to answer wbelow, i can upvote you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
:with => /\Adata:image\/jpeg;base64\S*\z/i
```

where `\S*` matches zero or more non-whitespace chars and `\z` matches the end of string.

See [the Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/HLu8n8M6QB).